# Update the source of multiple charts to new sheet?

Tags: excel

I'm using Office 2010.  I have a sheet with 30 charts, each getting the data from another sheet.  I would like to make a copy of both, make some changes to the data, and have the new charts use the changed data on the new sheet.  I know I can manually change the data source of each of the 30 charts, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a faster way (like a replace all), because I need to do this often.  My search on the web has only found updating the range within a sheet, but here I need to use a different sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Indireft Reference. Following the scheme:

[image]

you can switch quickly from Char1 to Char2 changing the reference in the cell B12. Changing the value with the first cell of the chart you want to show.
The formulas are:

```
B14 -> =INDIRECT(B12)
B15 -> =OFFSET(INDIRECT(B12);1;0)
B16 -> =OFFSET(INDIRECT(B12);2;0)
...

C14 -> =OFFSET(INDIRECT(B12);0;1)
C15 -> =OFFSET(INDIRECT(B12);1;1)
C16 -> =OFFSET(INDIRECT(B12);2;1)
...
```

The chart Data are taken from B14:C16.
Adding reference / calculation, you can update with different number of row and column, but if you need this it's better (and more friendly) use VBA.